# Make img held within div brighten/glow while hovering the div ONLY

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I'd like to make an image held within a div brighten but do so while hovering the div only, so that only the image within the div changes. My code may be a little sloppy but here it is, thank you.

```css
#textimg{
    
    background-image: url('images/stock1.jpg');
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 340px;
    max-width: 400px;
   
}



#textimg:hover{

     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;   
}



#textimg img:hover{

    -webkit-filter: brightness(140%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;

}
```

```html
<div id="textimg">
      <img src="images/sometext.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
#textimage:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(140%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is opacity.
Change the opacity vale on hover and it works.

There is an example for your reference:-

```
.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}   
.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

change your div according to the needs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to the image

```css
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    
}
.img1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
.img1:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/162389/lost-places-old-decay-ruin-162389.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" class="img1" />
 </div>
```